# Does React Router interfere with Axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios

I am new to the world of React so please keep that in mind when reading my question.

In my code I'm making a get request with `axios` and it works fine when printing it out in the console. Here's a snippet:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { numToDisplay, data } = this.props

    this.serverRequest = axios
      .get('http://blablabla/locks')
      .then(res => {
        // Rerender state
        console.log(res)
        this.setState({
          res,
          dataToDisplay: res.data.slice(0, numToDisplay || 5),
          allAreShowing: res.data.length < numToDisplay
        })
      })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.serverRequest.abort()
  }

  viewAllData() {
    this.setState({
      dataToDisplay: this.state.data,
      allAreShowing: true
    })
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.res) // Prints here!
```

But in my application I'd like to add Routes (I've never used React routes before) so I can navigate. So in my `layout.js` file I got this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import MainNavbar from './Navbar'
import AddButton from './AddButton'
import Doors from './Doors'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

export default class Layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <MainNavbar />
            <AddButton />
            <Doors />
          </Switch>
        </Router>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm importing the `BrowserRouter` as `Router` and I'm also importing `Switch`. I'm using `Switch` because it only renders the first child of `<Router />` and because it removed the error: `A 'Router' may have only one child element`.

#### My question

However now that the error is gone and all of my components render, the get request from axios wont' fetch. So my question is why. Has it to do something with react router?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: have use used something like React.cloneElement ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that in my `Layout.js` file I needed to add a `div`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import MainNavbar from './Navbar'
import AddButton from './AddButton'
import Doors from './Doors'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

export default class Layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div> // Forgot this!
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <MainNavbar />
            <AddButton />
            <Doors />
          </Switch>
        </Router>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```